# Non-measurable function over a finite set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to construct a non-measurable function
$$f: \{0, 1\}^n \to [0,1] \text{ ?}$$

Comment: What is the sigma algebra on the domain?

Comment: Let's say that I am taking $\mathcal{P}(\{0,1\}^n)$.

Comment: Then every set is measurable in $\{0,1\}^n$, so there are no non-measurable functions to anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the domain is given the sigma algebra of all subsets every function is automatically measurable by definition.